# Div Containing <img> and <p> getting formatted like link

Tags: html

As seen below, I have  3 links inside a div with a class of "nav", and then 4 divs in a div with a class of "contact-info", each containing an image and some text.

Now for some reason, which I can't figure out, my divs inside "contact-info" are underlined and turn red when clicked, as if they would've been a link. This is even without giving it any css.

If anyone could look into my script and tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
<!DOCKTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Log In</li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
        <div class="contact-info">
                <div class="home">
                    <img id="home" src="images\home.png"/>
                    <p>Company Name<br></br>Company Address<br></br>City, State Zip</p>
                </div>
                <div class="phone">
                    <img id="phone" src="images\telephone.png"/>
                    <p>Phone Number</p>
                </div>
                <div class="fax">
                    <img id="fax" src="images\fax.png"/>
                    <p>Fax Number</p>
                </div>
                <div class="email">
                    <img id="email" src="images\email.png"/>
                    <p>Email Address</p>    
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your browser's DOM inspector tell you?

Comment: You are missing the close tags on your links `</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the link tags like this

```
<li><a href="#">Log In></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sign Up></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Hope this helps :)
Also, I just had another look at the code, and there is no need to close your break tags, just

```
<p>Company Name<br>Company Address<br>City, State Zip</p>
```

on its own Is fine, but I don't think it makes a real difference :)